# Uncaught TypeError: Type error with drawImage

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

I am new to HTML5 and the canvas element and in the last few weeks I have been trying to understand it better. Anyways I am getting a `Uncaught TypeError: Type error` when I am trying to change the red square from this code http://jsfiddle.net/kmHZt/10/ to this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmLmn.png. But when I try to I just always get that `Uncaught TypeError: Type error`. Here is the code I have currently http://jsfiddle.net/cCDFs/.

If you need me to explain something better just ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to pass a URL into `drawImage`, which you can't do - you need to load an image element and pass it instead, after the image has finished loading.

[This article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images) has examples of what I'm describing.

The code would end up something like this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(img, 2, 2);
}
img.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/k73egsW.png';
```

In fact, your code does it already when it loads and draws the tiles.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument you need to pass to drawImage is an Image or a Canvas object, not a string;

I didn't quite get what you try to achieve with your code, but if you replace your draw() call to your function by code like this:

```
var otherImageObj = new Image();
otherImageObj.onload = function() {
        context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
        for (y = 0; y <= vHeight; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x <= vWidth; x++) {
                theX = x * 32;
                theY = y * 32;
                context.drawImage(tiles[board[y+vY][x+vX]], theX, theY, 32, 32);
            }
        }
        context.drawImage(otherImageObj, 2, 2);

};
otherImageObj.src = "http://i.imgur.com/k73egsW.png";
```

Your code actually works, albeit, getting a "403 (Forbidden)" error for your image.